# STL container of structure having character array elements

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

Lets say I have structure that looks like below -

```
struct Member
{
    Membe(char* member1In, char* member2In)
    {
       strcpy(member1, member1In);
       strcpy(member2, member2In);
    }
    char member1[10];
    char member2[10];
};
```

and std::vector declared as

```
std::vector<Member> members{};
```

And I insert values using `emplace_back()` like below

```
members.emplace_back(value1, value2);
```

So my question is when array grows beyond capacity, it has to move to some other location. Who will allocate memory for Member structure ? Do I have to write my own copy, assignment and move operations or compiler provided are enough ?  Will default provided operation do shallow copy and create problem ?

Comment: note that `char member1[10]` is no pointer, it is an array. The data is stored right there in the object, no indirection, no danger of shallow copy doing the wrong thing.

Comment: there is a typo in your constructor, it should be "Member" not "Membe"

Comment: Note passing arrays as pointers is bug-prone, std::array is your friend or in your case even std::string or std::string_view depending on whether or not you actually need to copy the data

Answer (score 5):

> Who will allocate memory for Member structure ?

`std::vector` will allocate the memory using the allocator that you provided (implicitly, by using the default argument).

> Do I have to write my own copy, assignment and move operations or compiler provided are enough ?

The compiler provided ones are enough.

> Will default provided operation do shallow copy

Yes, although it depends on what one means by shallow copy. The distinction between shallow and deep copy is only meaningful to referential types.

> and create problem ?

No. Your class contains no pointers / references / iterators, so there is nothing that could be copied deeply, and no problem.

Answer (score 2):

The vector will allocate the necessary memory.

For some classes you would need to write a copy constructor etc. But that would be true even if you weren't using the class in a vector.

For your class however the default copy constructor will work correctly. The simple rule of thumb is that if your class needs a destructor, then it also needs a copy constructor and an assignment operator. This is called the rule of three.